# How to solve duplicate column error with weak entities using Go-GORM?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I'm using Gin, GORM, and mySQL, I have two weak entities with composite primary key [like this](https://gorm.io/docs/composite_primary_key.html):

```
type FavoriteWord struct {
    WordID   uint `json:"word_ID" gorm:"type:INT NOT NULL;primaryKey;autoIncrement:false"`
    UserID   uint `json:"user_ID" gorm:"type:INT NOT NULL;primaryKey;autoIncrement:false"`
}

type FavoritePhrase struct {
    PhraseID uint `json:"phrase_ID" gorm:"type:INT NOT NULL;primaryKey;autoIncrement:false"`
    UserID   uint `json:"user_ID" gorm:"type:INT NOT NULL;primaryKey;autoIncrement:false"`
}
```

But when using `database.AutoMigrate(&FavoriteWord{})` Go runtime throws:

- `Error 1060: Duplicate column name 'user_id'`.
- `ALTER TABLE favorite_words ADD user_id varchar(191)`
  (IDK why it tries to type user_id as varchar(191) when it's declared as uint)

And when using `database.AutoMigrate(&FavoritePhrase{})` Go runtime throws:

- `Error 1060: Duplicate column name 'user_id'`.
- `ALTER TABLE favorite_phrases ADD phrase_id bigint unsigned`

[Other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=duplicate+column+error+gorm) state the same problem using `gorm.Model`, but I haven't used it at all.

The (minimal) SQL is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`user`(
    `ID` INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`phrase`(
    `ID` INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    `text` TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`word`(
    `ID` INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    `text` TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`favorite_phrases`(
    `phrase_ID` INT NOT NULL,
    `user_ID` INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (`phrase_ID`) REFERENCES `test`.`phrase`(`ID`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_ID`) REFERENCES `test`.`user`(`ID`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`favorite_words`(
    `word_ID` INT NOT NULL,
    `user_ID` INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (`word_ID`) REFERENCES `test`.`word`(`ID`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_ID`) REFERENCES `test`.`user`(`ID`)
);
```

Comment: Tried to run `AutoMigrate` with your struct definition and got no error (on a postgres db). Can you provide the code that you've actually tried and point where it produces the error that you describe?

Comment: @EzequielMuns I've updated the question, the previous example had a typo in the SQL, but I've triple checked these and added their SQL. (Note: I'm using mySQL)

Comment: I run `AutoMigrate` with your updated structs, and against a MySQL database, and still get no error. This means the error you're seeing is to do with something else that you're doing. It's interesting that it's throwing a duplicate key error, that would imply it is trying to re-add a column. Maybe including more of your actual go migration code could provide more insight.

Comment: Note that I run the Migration on a MySQL database after having run your minimal SQL on it first, as well as without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the optional GORM `column` tag could be necessary when automigrating the database. And checking the logger (explained later), I saw GORM duplicated all of my singular named tables, into plural named tables, apparently this is a feature.

I've managed to solve the problem setting GORM to name tables in singular:

```
dsn := "user:password@tcp(localhost:3306)/db?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local"
database, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{
    NamingStrategy: schema.NamingStrategy{
        SingularTable: true, // !!!
    },
})
```

And using the GORM `column` tag in every struct:

```
type FavoritePhrase struct {
    PhraseID uint   `json:"phrase_ID" gorm:"column:phrase_ID;type:INT NOT NULL;primaryKey;autoIncrement:false"`
    UserID   uint   `json:"user_ID" gorm:"column:user_ID;type:INT NOT NULL;primaryKey;autoIncrement:false"`
}

type FavoriteWord struct {
    WordID   uint   `json:"word_ID" gorm:"column:word_ID;type:INT NOT NULL;primaryKey;autoIncrement:false"`
    UserID   uint   `json:"user_ID" gorm:"column:user_ID;type:INT NOT NULL;primaryKey;autoIncrement:false"`
}
```

A good tip for other users trying to debug these type of errors is using a logger:

```
f, err := os.OpenFile("testlogfile", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error opening file: %v", err)
}
defer f.Close()

newLogger := logger.New(
    log.New(f, "\r\n", log.LstdFlags), // io writer
    logger.Config{
        SlowThreshold: time.Second, // Slow SQL threshold
        LogLevel:      logger.Info, // Log level
        Colorful:      true,        // Allow color
    },
)

dsn := "user:password@tcp(localhost:3306)/db?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local"
database, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{
    Logger: newLogger,
})

//... automigrate & etc
```

And consulting the DB the same queries that GORM logged, to see if the actual table was altered by GORM, or what is it trying to alter

```
SELECT column_name, is_nullable, data_type, character_maximum_length, numeric_precision, numeric_scale, datetime_precision FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'db' AND table_name = 'table';
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by weak entities? I'm not sure what you've solved because you haven't provided code that errors out, as far as I can see.

Comment: Sure @EzequielMuns , a weak entity in databases is a table whose elements cannot be uniquely identified by one attribute alone (AKA primary key). So, you can only identify them by the sum of it's attributes. You could uniquely identify them by having foreign keys as attributes that form a unique combo (AKA composite primary key) with no duplicates. In my case, I have more than those two weak entities with some shared (and previously undisclosed with the `column` tag) foreign key columns, which apparently confused GORM interpreter, which then tried to add it's own primary key column.